# linux kernel fullpath from file struct

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

Good day. Im trying to get fullpath from struct file

```
char *buf = (char*)__get_free_page(GFP_USER);
char *buf2 = (char*)__get_free_page(GFP_USER);

char *name =  dentry_path(file->f_dentry, buf, PAGE_SIZE);
char *root = dentry_path(file->f_vfsmnt->mnt_mountpoint, buf2, PAGE_SIZE);

***some operations***

free_page((unsigned long)buf);
free_page((unsigned long)buf2);
kfree(*root);
kfree(*name);
```

But i get an error
fs/read_write.c:707: error: request for member 'mnt_mountpoint' in something not a structure or union

How can i get vsfmount struct from file?

Kernel version linux-2.6.37.6

Comment: Is there any difference? As i understand any file in a system can be presented with a struct file.  struct file {
   
    union {
        struct list_head    fu_list;
        struct rcu_head     fu_rcuhead;
    } f_u; 
    struct path     f_path;
#define f_dentry    f_path.dentry
#define f_vfsmnt    f_path.mnt

Comment: It seems that your code doesn't follow the kernel version. Take a look at `include/linux/fs.h`, `include/linux/path.h` and `fs/mount.h`. You need to use `container_of` for `f_vfsmnt` which now is a part of private `mount` struct.

Comment: Ilya, kernel version is linux-2.6.37.6. struct file has struct path     f_path; and defined link to mnt of path - #define f_vfsmnt    f_path.mnt, mnt itself has mnt_root and mnt_mountpoint

Comment: Can you try to check it with `#include <linux/mount.h>` added in `read_write.c` ?

Comment: Oh, i got it! There was no. Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

In kernel 2.6, your code should work.

In kernel 3.0, `struct vfsmount` contains member `mnt_root`, of type `struct dentry`.
I think this would give you the mount point path.

Which are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the error, is it possible that `f_vfsmnt` is allocated in the `file`-struct?

I that case the `mnt_mountpoint` field should be accessible via `file->f_vfsmnt.mnt_mountpoint`.